# When setting InheritGlobal to true for all subsites using PowerShell, SharePoint 2013 doesn't reflect changes

Tags: sharepoint, powershell

I'm trying to set all the sub-sites to inherits the parent navigation using PowerShell script since I have 100s of sub-sites. After I have run the PowerShell script, the SharePoint 2013 sub-sites don't reflex the changes, even though the navigation setting for "Display the same navigation as parent" is now checked. It appears that the setting has been updated, but not applied.

The PowerShell script I am running is:

```
# get a sitecollection object(SPSite)
$SPSite = Get-SPSite -Identity "http://intranet/pm"

# loop through all the subwebs(SPWebs) in the site collection
foreach ($SPWeb in $SPSite.AllWebs)
{
   # check so that this is not the root web
  if (!$SPWeb.IsRootWeb)
  {

     # Save AllowUnsafeUpdates setting and set it to allow.
     $AllowUnsafeUpdatesStatus = $SPWeb.AllowUnsafeUpdates
     $SPWeb.AllowUnsafeUpdates = $true

     # Get a PublishingWeb object for the current web
     $SPPubWeb = [Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.PublishingWeb]::GetPublishingWeb($SPWeb)

     #Current Navigation Settings
     $SPPubWeb.Navigation.InheritGlobal = $true
     $SPPubWeb.Update()

     # cleanup 
     # Set AllowUnsafeUpdates back to original value
     $SPWeb.AllowUnsafeUpdates = $AllowUnsafeUpdatesStatus

     Write-Host -ForegroundColor Green $SPWeb.Url.ToString()  " - Done"

     $SPWeb.Dispose()
 }

 # cleanup
 $SPSite.Dispose()
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Regards

Mugilan

Answer (score 0):

Please check whether **SharePoint Server Publishing Infrastructure** is activated at site collection level and check whether for both the "Global Navigation" and "Current Navigation" section it is checked.